# Javascript onload on img fired immediately, when srcset is used

Tags: javascript, image, onload, srcset

I'm creating image preloading, using an invisible img with srcset, so images should be preloaded with size user needs.
Here is function for preload:

```
function preload() {
DOM.viewAreaPreload.html(Mark.up(slideTemplate, {
    presentation: preloadList[0].presentation,
    filename: preloadList[0].filename,
    preload: true
}));
preloadList.splice(0, 1);
console.log('loaded!');
if (preloadList.length > 0) {
    DOM.viewAreaPreload.find('img').onload = preload();
}}
```

DOM.viewAreaPreload is a jQuery-object for an invisible container for my preloading images

I use markup.js for templating. 
Here is my slideTemplate:

```
<img src="/presentations/{{presentation|url}}/{{filename|url}}" {{if preload}} id="image-preload" {{/if}}
 srcset="
      /presentations/{{presentation|url}}/{{filename|url}} 1600w,
      /presentations/{{presentation|url}}/1024x768/{{filename|url}} 1024w,
      /presentations/{{presentation|url}}/800x600/{{filename|url}} 800w,
      /presentations/{{presentation|url}}/400x300/{{filename|url}} 400w"
 sizes="90vw">
```

preloadList is an array, containing objects like this: {presentation: 'first', filename: 'slide01.jpg'}

What do I expect: images are loading consequentially; onload fires only when image is fully loaded.

What do I get: all onloads fires within a half-second or so. I get all my image requests queued, they are loading asyncroniously, not in the sequence I need.

How do I make onload event fire only when image is fully loaded?

Comment: `DOM.viewAreaPreload.find('img').onload = preload;` ?!

Comment: Yes, I've created new img tag (erasing previous) and added new event handler for it. Yes, it is recursive. But could you be more specific about what are you so amused of? Maybe I can't see something obvious?

Comment: I'm not sure your comment is regarding my previous comment but as i see it, you should use the reference to function, not calling the function, so: `DOM.viewAreaPreload.find('img').onload = preload;` instead of `DOM.viewAreaPreload.find('img').onload = preload();`, so ***.preload;*** instead of ***.preload();***. Does it fix your issue?

Comment: I can't understand, how I couldn't see it without your help :'D. Well, now only one image is loading, but I seem to understand how make this work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. My main issue was, thanks to [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff), that I have accidentally used () when I assigned callback for DOM.viewAreaPreload.find('img').onload.
2. Even when I've fixed that, only one image was loading, so I used jQuery's on('load') event, that worked perfeclty